# Animating the solution to the Insulated 2D Heat equation with inital condition in a rectangular region

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am very new to mathematica and I tried to give my best shot at animating the 2d heat equation with a given initial condition:

```
heqn  = D[u[x, y, t], t] == Laplacian[u[x, y, t], {x, y}];

ic = u[x, y, 0] == x+y;

bca = DirichletCondition[Derivative[u[x, 10, t], x] == 0, True];

bcb =DirichletCondition[Derivative[u[10, y, t], y] == 0, True];
bc = {bca, bcb}

sol = NDSolveValue[{heqn, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 30}];
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
NDSolveValue::fembdnl: The dependent variable in Derivative[u,x]==0 in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[Derivative[u,x]==0,True] needs to be linear.

NDSolveValue::fembdnl: The dependent variable in Derivative[u,x]==0 in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[Derivative[u,x]==0,True] needs to be linear.

NDSolveValue::fembdnl: The dependent variable in Derivative[u,x]==0 in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[Derivative[u,x]==0,True] needs to be linear.

General::stop: Further output of NDSolveValue::fembdnl will be suppressed during this calculation.

NDSolveValue::fembdnl: The dependent variable in Derivative[u,x]==0 in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[Derivative[u,x]==0,True] needs to be linear.

NDSolveValue::fembdnl: The dependent variable in Derivative[u,x]==0 in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[Derivative[u,x]==0,True] needs to be linear.
```

Please Help me and tell me where i went wrong.

**EDIT:**
My revised code but it is still not working:

```
heqn = D[u[x, y, t], t] == Laplacian[u[x, y, t], {x, t}]

shape = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}]

ic = u[x, y, 0] == x+y

bc = NeumannValue[0, True]

sol = NDSolveValue[{heqn == bc, ic},u, {t, 0, 30}, {x, y} \[Element] shape]

NDSolveValue::femnotime: The differential equation cannot be solved as a time dependent equation as specified, most likely because the initial conditions given at (t==0.) are not sufficient to define an initial value problem. As a consequence the differential equation will be solved as a time independent equation.

NDSolveValue::femnlmdor: The maximum derivative order of the nonlinear PDE coefficients for the Finite Element Method is larger than 1. It may help to rewrite the PDE in inactive form.
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Heat Transfer Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html)?  There are quite a few examples.  Also, are you trying to specify a flux condition with the `DirichletCondition`?  You should use `NeumannValue` to specify a flux condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, one can follow the [Heat Transfer Tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html) to quickly set up a variety of heat transfer related problems.

We can copy the code to set up operators for steady-state and transient problems:

```
ClearAll[HeatTransferModel]
HeatTransferModel[T_, X_List, k_, ρ_, Cp_, Velocity_, Source_] :=
  Module[{V, Q, a = k}, 
  V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 
    0, ρ*Cp*Velocity.Inactive[Grad][T, X]];
  Q = If[Source === "NoSource", 0, Source];
  If[FreeQ[a, _?VectorQ], a = a*IdentityMatrix[Length[X]]];
  If[VectorQ[a], a = DiagonalMatrix[a]];
  (*Note the-sign in the operator*)
  a = PiecewiseExpand[Piecewise[{{-a, True}}]];
  Inactive[Div][a.Inactive[Grad][T, X], X] + V - Q]
TimeHeatTransferModel[T_, TimeVar_, X_List, k_, ρ_, Cp_, 
  Velocity_, Source_] := ρ*Cp*D[T, {TimeVar, 1}] + 
  HeatTransferModel[T, X, k, ρ, Cp, Velocity, Source]
```

We can follow one of the many examples and adapt it to your problem.  The default `NeumannValue` is zero flux, which is the case for insulated walls.  I adapted the example from [here](https://wolfram.com/xid/0hqp56s8dz09d27n66vyfgbsvtjae0yi-3n02io) for your problem.

```
Ω2D = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}];
tend = 30;
parameters = {ρ -> 1, Cp -> 1, k -> 1};
ic = u[0, x, y] == x + y;
pde = {TimeHeatTransferModel[u[t, x, y], t, {x, y}, k, ρ, Cp, 
      "NoFlow", "NoSource"] == 0, ic} /. parameters;
ufun = NDSolveValue[pde, 
   u, {t, 0, tend}, {x, y} ∈ Ω2D];
pRange = MinMax[ufun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
legendBar = 
  BarLegend[{"BrightBands", pRange}, 
   Sequence[50, LegendLabel -> Style["[°C]", Opacity[0.6]]]];
options = {PlotRange -> pRange, 
   Sequence[ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"BrightBands", pRange}], 
    ContourStyle -> None, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Transient Temperature Field: u(t,x,y)", 18], 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, Contours -> 75, PlotPoints -> 41, 
    ImageSize -> Medium]};
nframes = 30;
frames = Table[
   Show[Legended[
     ContourPlot[ufun[t, x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω2D, 
      Evaluate[options]], legendBar]], {t, 0, tend, tend/nframes}];
frames = Rasterize[#1, "Image", ImageResolution -> 80] & /@ frames;
ListAnimate[Sequence[frames, SaveDefinitions -> True], 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image: Transient Evolution]

## Updated Response to Edited Code

The OP edited the code to produce:

```
heqn = D[u[x, y, t], t] == Laplacian[u[x, y, t], {x, t}]

shape = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}]

ic = u[x, y, 0] == x+y

bc = NeumannValue[0, True]

sol = NDSolveValue[{heqn == bc, ic},u, {t, 0, 30}, {x, y} ∈ shape]
```

First, you should have your independent variables have consistent ordering with the NDSolve specification.  Namely, `{t, 0, 30}, {x, y} ∈ shape` means that the dependent variable should be defined with variables `{t,x,y}` or `u[t,x,y]`.

Second, your Laplacian specification differentiated `{x,t}`, when it should be `{x,y}`.

Third, your `heqn` already contains `==`.  For the FEM method to work, you will want to express your equation in coefficient form, or:

$$\frac{{{\partial ^2}}}{{\partial {t^2}}}u + d\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}u + \nabla \cdot\left( { - c\nabla u - \alpha u + \gamma } \right) + \beta \cdot\nabla u + au - f = 0$$

So, you pull all terms of the operator to the left hand side and replace the $0$ on the right hand side with a sum of `NeumannValue`s.

The corrected code for your edit should look like this:

```
op = D[u[t, x, y], t] - Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}]

shape = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}]

ic = u[0, x, y] == x + y

sol = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, ic}, 
  u, {t, 0, 30}, {x, y} ∈ shape]
```

Comment: Thank you but what was wrong with my code

Comment: @MayurMatada You specified that the boundaries were insulated.  As mentioned in my comment, the correct way to specify an insulated boundary is with a `NeumannCondition` and you used `DirichletCondition`.  As mentioned in my answer, the default `NeumannCondition` is an insulated wall.

Comment: but what is wrong what is wrong with my edited code..And yes it was stupid of me to use dirichlet conditions

Comment: @MayurMatada I updated my answer to include your edit.  I would still advise you to use the tutorial as it will construct a well formed pde operator that you can study and perturb it to suit your purpose.

Comment: thank you this has solved my problem and yes i am very new to diffrential equations as a whole and i will make sure to check the tutorial. Also could you help me 1 last time and show how to animate it.Sorry if i am bothering you too much